# Insert Form Buttons to Cell but Format Buttons to be Smaller then Cell Dimensions

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the following code to insert form button if there is a value in column "A".  I am trying to get the form buttons to be slightly smaller than the cell dimensions (not touch the cell walls).  This is what I have so far:

```
Sub InsertButtons()
Dim i As Long
Dim shp As Object
Dim dblLeft As Double
Dim dblTop As Double
Dim dblWidth As Double
Dim dblHeight As Double


With Sheets("MailMerge")

    dblLeft = .Columns("N:N").Left 
    dblWidth = .Columns("N:N").Width - 1

    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        dblHeight = .Rows(i).Height -1
        dblTop = .Rows(i).Top

        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = Empty Then

        Else

            Set shp = .Buttons.Add(dblLeft, dblTop, dblWidth, dblHeight)
            shp.OnAction = "SendEmail"
            shp.Characters.Text = "Email"

        End If

    Next i

End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: ...and? why are you posting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subtract `2` from width and height. And add `1` to top and left:

```
dblLeft = .Columns("N:N").Left + 1
dblWidth = .Columns("N:N").Width - 2

dblHeight = .Rows(i).Height - 2
blTop = .Rows(i).Top + 1
```

I also recommend to use

```
If Not .Cells(i, 1).Value = Empty Then
    Set shp = .Buttons.Add(dblLeft, dblTop, dblWidth, dblHeight)
    shp.OnAction = "SendEmail"
    shp.Characters.Text = "Email"
End If
```

instead of an empty `If` statement.